# What would be "faster" when dealing with input and output?

Tags: java, performance, io

A simple program asking for user input could use datainputstream or scanner. Which would be faster? Datainputstream is binary so it may be faster? Is it in opinion? I'm just curious because I'm building a program that I want to be efficient as possible.

Comment: Both solutions are several thousand times quicker than the fastest user I've ever seen. If I were you, I'd concentrate on my code being readable and efficiently organised.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are taking input from a human being you shouldn't worry about optimizing the method in which you retrieve it.

The amount of time it takes a user to type will be the only substantial bottleneck in your program.  People are many times slower than computers, so don't worry about making your program fast.

What you should worry about is making it easier for people to enter data into your program.  That is the only way to substantially speed up human input.

(That being said, I prefer the `Scanner` class for reading input from a user.)

Comment: Thank you for the input. I guess I did word my question poorly. I mean as in general what would be better for passing data back and forth between two objects?

Comment: @Denis, use scanner unless you want to take advantage of serialization of objects.  The two methods you mention are really not very similar at all.